# definition of static arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, static, definition, characteristics

I've been looking for a decent definition of static arrays.  I've tried using msdn and c# sources but cannot seem to find a definition.  It gives examples, but no definitions...

Does anyone know any links or definitions and characteristics of a static array please?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a definition of "static"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you talk about a 'static array' you are really talking about two separate things.

One would be the `static` keyword.  When applied to variables this means that the variable lives at the `class` level, and each object of that type will not get its own instance.

An `array` is simply a data structure for holding multiple values of some type.

So, a `static array` is simply an array at the class level that can hold multiple of some data type.

For example:

In your `TravelRoute` class, you may have a set number of possible destinations in a route.  These could be defined like so:

```
class TravelRoute {
    public static Destination[] possibleDestinations = 
           new Destination[]{
                 new Destination("New York"),
                 new Destination("Minneapolis"),
                 new Destination("NParis")
           };
}
```

This will define the possible destinations on a `TravelRoute`.  You can then access the array like so:

```
Destination one = TravelRoute.possibleDestinations[0];
```

Answer (score 9):

Do you possibly mean fixed size arrays?

```
unsafe struct Foo
{
    fixed int Values[8];
}
```

If so, you will get more search results by using fixed size arrays as your query :)

Comment: a fixed size array is what i eventually understood a static array to be, so thank you mattDavey for your input! it was much appeciated

Comment: Any way to add a fixed size array as a member in a class?

Comment: @DeanP No, "Fixed size buffer fields may only be members of structs". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1642

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing (that I know of) that's special about static arrays, per se, which may be why you're having trouble finding good write-ups about them.   Correct me if I'm wrong, but I wonder if it's the "static" part that you're most interested in?   Basically, static means that the member exists at the class level rather than the instance level, so a static array would be an array that belongs to the class (rather than an instance of the class).

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static int[] Numbers {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
   public int[] Numbers {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
     public void Main()
     {
// NOTE: Foo itself has this array
          Foo.Numbers = new int[]{1,2,3};

// NOTE: it's this particular instance of a Bar that has this array
           Bar bar = new Bar();
           bar.Numbers = new int[]{1,2,3};

     }
}
```